# Update from existing table in Redshift

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I would like to update a value in Redshift table from results of other table, I'm trying to run to following query but received an error.

```
update section_translate
set word=t.section_type
from (
select distinct section_type from mr_usage where section_type like '%sディスコ')t
where word = '80sディスコ'
```

The error I received:

```
ERROR: Target table must be part of an equijoin predicate
```

Can't understand what is incorrect in my query.

Comment: The subquery must result in **exactly one** result row (per target row). Yours *could* yield more than one result row.

Comment: the query receive only one result

Comment: did you run the subquery separately? (`select distinct section_type from mr_usage where section_type like '%sディスコ';` ) Besides, it is uncorrelated  to the main query. Best way to test is to temporally replace the `UPDATE x set y = z ...` by the corresponmding  `SELECT x.*, z ...` and see what would be the result.

Comment: FYI, that error is referenced on this documentation page regarding OUTER joins (but that doesn't seem to be the situation here): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Examples_of_UPDATE_statements.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the uncorrelated subquery to a correlated subquery,

```
update section_translate
set word=t.section_type
from (
select distinct section_type,'80sディスコ' as word  from mr_usage where section_type like '%sディスコ')t
where section_translate.word = t.word
```

Otherwise, each record of the outer query is eligible for updates and the query engine rejects it. The way Postgre (and thus Redshift) evaluates uncorrelated subqueries is slightly different from SQL Server/ Oracle etc.